# How and why does the Laravel cookie persist between redirects but setting it in the global cookie variable does not?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, middleware

So in a recent problem which I was trying to solve I had to authenticate a user from a third party platform and land him/her directly into our dashboard. Ignoring how the authentication works here. The problem is after I authenticate the request I need to modify a cookie 'xyz' before redirecting it to a different route. Now when i tried to do this

```
setcookie('xyz', 1);
$_COOKIE['xyz'] = 1;
return redirect('/myroute');
```

would 0 or '' in /myroute Controller method.

But if I add 'xyz' to exceptions of my EncryptCookies middleware of laravel and do

```
$cookie = cookie('xyz', 1);
return redirect('/myroute')->withCookie($cookie);
```

That would give me the value of xyz successfully in /myroute Controller method.

What exactly is happening in the later method (the laravel way) and the first way? Its getting pretty confusing because according to what i know cookies can only be queued to be modified but are only modified after the response is returned to the client. Please point me out my mistakes and shed some light.

Comment: Tricky to tell - can you post your cookies (from the application developer tab in Chrome) from both scenarios?

Comment: Exactly! Had it been a modification between a server to client request I am certain it would have been simple. But its a scenario where after the first request is made a redirect is made without sending the response back to client.